# CSS border element not working properly in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I'm using border with the following properties:

```
 border-left:0.5rem solid #d8f4fd;
   border-right:0.5rem solid #d8f4fd;
   border-bottom:0.5rem solid #2e3d98;
   border-top:0.5rem solid #d8f4fd;
```

and took the height:56px; and width:56px; and border-radius:50%;
my browser is displaying disc with diameter 56px+8px+8px [border is displayed outside the element]
while using the same in wordpress, its showing an element with 56 diameter and border is displayed with in the element 
I want the border to get displayed outside the element.

Comment: an we get a live example or working code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly because the element has `box-sizing: border-box;` rather than the default `box-sizing: content-box;`. This may be coming from a reset stylesheet or elsewhere in your theme CSS.

```css
.bordered {
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-left: 0.5rem solid #d8f4fd;
  border-right: 0.5rem solid #d8f4fd;
  border-bottom: 0.5rem solid #2e3d98;
  border-top: 0.5rem solid #d8f4fd;
}

.content-box {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.border-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<p>content-box : Border will be added to width / height</p>
<div class="bordered content-box">

</div>

<p>border-box : Border will be included in width / height</p>
<div class="bordered border-box">

</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The main reason behind the extra pixels is because you are not using `display: inline-block;` and `box-sizing: content-box;`

So if you follow this code you wont get any extra pixels:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    display: inline-block;
}
.circle{
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 5px solid #d8f4fd;
    border-left: 5px solid #d8f4fd;
    border-right: 5px solid #d8f4fd;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #2e3d98;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Remember that if you do work in Wordpress , please give an css !impotrant
color: #000000 !important;

Answer (score -2):

use border radius in pixels like  border-radius:28px;

Comment: If you want to make a circle than you have to use `border-radius : 50%;` to make it round. No need to give in pixels!